# selenium can't recognize href hypertext

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use selenium to click on some links from web page's source. This is what I got so far:

```
import selenium, time
import html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
pg_src = br.page_source.encode("utf")
soup = BeautifulSoup(pg_src)
br = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "http://somewikipage.org"

br.get(url)

lnkLst = soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile(",_California") # this builds a list with everything in the a href tag

nuLst = []

for i in lnkLst:

    nuLst.append(i.get('href')) #this removes all the unclickable text from the a href tag

for i in nuLst:

    br.find_element_by_link_text(i).click()
```

This results in the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

I've printed out nuLst and each item exactly matches the hyperlink within the href tags. I did something similar before using find_element_by_xpath but I am not sure how to isolate the css selectors for this groups of hrefs without calling all other hrefs on the page.

Comment: i think the error from: br.find_element_by_link_text(i),  the argument: i is a url of the link , not the text of the link.  so you should append the link text into nuLst not href  at:  nuLst.append(i.get('href'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

You are trying to click on list of object(which has no click method), instead of clicking on a web element from the list of web element.

First get list of web element of all links

```
list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a")//Note, there is 'elements' not element
```

Now iterate through this list as per your requirement.

Comment: I got the list of elements using your code but the click action still didn't work. I ended up using a for loop and building a url from the iterable and then using br.get(url). This got me what I needed.

Comment: That's great. You can edit those in my above answer and mark it as correct so that it will be helpful for other.